# If a variable is passed as a constant does it get passed by reference?

Tags: pass-by-reference, pascal, pass-by-const-reference

If I pass a variable as a constant does it automatically get passed by reference?

```
procedure foo(const x : integer)
```

I can already pass a variable by reference like this:

```
procedure foo(var y : integer);
```

---

Ideally I'd want something like the code below:

```
procedure foo(const var z : integer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` does not guarantee that the value is actually passed by reference.

Free Pascal supports

```
procedure foo(constref z : integer);
```

for this purpose: z is always passed by reference in this case. I'am not aware of something similiar in other pascal compiler.

Comment: Out of curiosity, recent Delphi compilers (since Delphi XE4) uses the [`[Ref]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Constant_Parameters) decorator for this. You can write there e.g. `procedure foo(const [Ref] Z: Integer);`.